Controlled MUI Autocomplete not updating parent state
I'm working with React and Formik, I'm trying to use an Autocomplete component from MUI but the 'value' is not updating.
GeneralInfo
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
// prop-type is a library for typechecking of props
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

// @mui material components
import Grid from "@mui/material/Grid";

// components
import MDBox from "components/Generic/MDBox";
import MDTypography from "components/Generic/MDTypography";

// NewUser page components
import FormField from "components/Global/FormField";
import AutocompleteField from "components/Global/AutocompleteField";

function GeneralInfo({ formData }) {
  const { formField, values, errors, touched } = formData;
  const {
    requestorS3,
    organization,
    contractNumber,
    accountName,
    bcn,
    billingPlatform,
    discardedByCTC,
    startingSupportDate,
    supportTimeFrame,
    monthsOfDuration,
    specialRequirement,
    isPortalEntryByPO,
    fundsAvailable,
    customerSegment,
    monthlyFee,
  } = formField;

  const {
    requestorS3: requestorS3V,
    organization: organizationV,
    contractNumber: contractNumberV,
    accountName: accountNameV,
    bcn: bcnV,
    billingPlatform: billingPlatformV,
    startingSupportDate: startingSupportDateV,
    monthsOfDuration: monthsOfDurationV,
    specialRequirement: specialRequirementV,
    isPortalEntryByPO: isPortalEntryByPOV,
    fundsAvailable: fundsAvailableV,
    customerSegment: customerSegmentV,
    supportTimeFrame: supportTimeFrameV,
    discardedByCTC: discardedByCTCV,
    monthlyFee: monthlyFeeV
  } = values;

  const billingPlatformOptions = [
    "Platform 01",
    "Platform 02",
    "Platform 03",
    "Platform 04",
    "Platform 05",
  ]

  return (
    <MDBox>
      <MDBox lineHeight={0}>
        <MDTypography variant="h5">General Information</MDTypography>
        <MDTypography variant="button" color="text">
          General information
        </MDTypography>
      </MDBox>
      <MDBox mt={1.625} >
        <Grid container spacing={3}>
          <Grid item xs={12} sm={4}>
            <AutocompleteField
              freeSolo={true}
              name={billingPlatform.name}
              label={billingPlatform.label}
              value={billingPlatformV}
              options={billingPlatformOptions}
              onChange={console.table(values)}
            />
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </MDBox>
    </MDBox>
  );
}

// typechecking props for GeneralInfo
GeneralInfo.propTypes = {
  formData: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.object, PropTypes.func]).isRequired,
};

export default GeneralInfo;


AutocompleteField
// prop-type is a library for typechecking of props
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

// formik components
import { ErrorMessage, Field } from "formik";

// components
import MDBox from "components/Generic/MDBox";
import MDTypography from "components/Generic/MDTypography";
import MDAutocomplete from "components/Generic/MDAutocomplete";

import HelpOutlineIcon from "@mui/icons-material/HelpOutline"
import { Tooltip } from "@mui/material";

function AutocompleteField({ label, name, helpText, ...rest }) {
  return (
    <MDBox mb={1.5}>
      <span style={{display: 'block', flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center'}}>
        <Field {...rest} as={MDAutocomplete} variant="standard" label={label} name={name} />
        {helpText ? 
          (
            <Tooltip title={helpText}>
              <HelpOutlineIcon style={{
                color: 'var(--fc-neutral-text-color)',
                '&:hover': {
                  color: 'default !important'
                }
              }}/>
            </Tooltip>
          )
          :
          (<></>)
        }
      </span>
      <MDBox mt={0.75}>
        <MDTypography component="div" variant="caption" color="error" fontWeight="regular">
          <ErrorMessage name={name} />
        </MDTypography>
      </MDBox>
    </MDBox>
  );
}

// typechecking props for AutocompleteField
AutocompleteField.propTypes = {
  label: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  helpText: PropTypes.string
};

export default AutocompleteField;


MDAutocomplete
import { forwardRef } from "react";
import { Autocomplete, Box, TextField } from "@mui/material";

// prop-types is a library for typechecking of props
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

// Custom styles for MDAutocomplete
import MDAutocompleteRoot from "./MDAutocompleteRoot";

const MDAutocomplete = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const {
    error, success, disabled,
    options, label, value, onChange, name,
    ...rest
  } = props;

  return (
    <MDAutocompleteRoot ref={ref} ownerState={{ error, success, disabled }}>
      <Autocomplete {...rest}
        id={label.toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g, "_")+'_autocomplete_input'}
        name={name}

        forcePopupIcon={true}
        value={value}
        options={options}
        onChange={onChange}
        
        renderInput={params => <TextField {...params} label={label} />}
      />
    </ MDAutocompleteRoot>
)});

// Setting default values for the props of MDAutocomplete
MDAutocomplete.defaultProps = {
  error: false,
  success: false,
  disabled: false,
};

// Typechecking props for the MDAutocomplete
MDAutocomplete.propTypes = {
  error: PropTypes.bool,
  success: PropTypes.bool,
  disabled: PropTypes.bool,
  options: PropTypes.array,
  label: PropTypes.string,
  value: PropTypes.string,
  onChange: PropTypes.func,
  name: PropTypes.string
};

export default MDAutocomplete;


The constant that is controlling the AutocompleteField component is billingPlatformV, but after changing the value of the Autocomplete component the onChange event is fired but the value of billingPlatfromV doesn't change.
Originally, the options passed to the Autocomplete component were supposed to be objects {label: '', id: ''} but I changed it to strings to simplify it and make it work before upgrading.

The field name is "billingPlatform". I rendered the form fields and their values; every time I change the autocomplete value a new field is added to the form object: "billingPlatform-option-#" where # is the option index. The actual billingPlatform field that is the one I want to update only changes when I hit 'enter', however, in that case I get an error stating that a component is changing a controlled value. I don't understand what is happening..
